# regarding amortized analysis?

Tags: c

I have read amortized analysis in coreman but unable to understand what it realy is.
i went through internet but unable to understand.please someone make me understand.thanks

Comment: What's coreman? Do you mean Cormen, of *Introduction to Algorithms*?

Comment: Nobody is inclined to answer if you never accept any answer.

Comment: Please do yourself at least the pain of formulating your question correctly and to tag it with the correct tag. It seems that it would already be a good exercise to know what your question is about. Certainly not about `C`.

Comment: You went through the entire internet!?

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind amortized analysis is based on the idea of amortization in economics: you spend more money now, in order to save money over time. For example: you spend an extra $500 to buy the car with a more modern, more fuel-efficient engine, and over time, you amortize those $500 by saving gas.

The way that amortized analysis differs from most other kinds, is that it looks at a whole sequence of operations, not a single operation.

For example, worst-case analysis would look at insertion into a dynamic array and say "if the array is full, you need to copy the entire array into a bigger array, therefore the worst-case step complexity of inserting into a dynamic array is `Ο(n)`".

Amortized worst-case analysis would say that resizing only happens very seldomly, *and* it actually buys you the possibility of doing insertions in `Ο(1)` for the foreseeable future. So, while the worst-case for one individual insertion is `Ο(n)`, this worst-case will only appear `Ο(1)` times every `Ω(n)` operations, which means the cost of resizing the array is amortized over the lifetime of the array, so the overall amortized worst-case step complexity of inserting into a dynamic array is `Ο(1)`.

Comment: Very good answer, although I don't think the questioner deserves it so much.